# errors with tensorflow reshape and resize layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I want to reshape and resize an image in the first layers before using Conv2D and other layers. The input will be a flattend array. Here is my code:

```
#Create flat example image:
img_test = np.zeros((120,160))
img_test_flat = img_test.flatten()

reshape_model = Sequential()
reshape_model.add(tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(img_test_flat.shape)))
reshape_model.add(tf.keras.layers.Reshape((120, 160,1)))
reshape_model.add(tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.Resizing(28, 28, interpolation='nearest'))

result = reshape_model(img_test_flat)
result.shape
```

Unfortunately this code results in the error I added down below. What is the issue and how do I correctly reshape and resize the flattend array?

```
    WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (None, 19200) for input Tensor("input_13:0", shape=(None, 19200), dtype=float32), but it was called on an input with incompatible shape (19200,).

InvalidArgumentError: Input to reshape is a tensor with 19200 values, but the requested shape has 368640000 [Op:Reshape]
```

EDIT:
I tried:

```
reshape_model = Sequential()
reshape_model.add(tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(None, img_test_flat.shape[0])))
reshape_model.add(tf.keras.layers.Reshape((120, 160,1)))
reshape_model.add(tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.Resizing(28, 28, interpolation='nearest'))
```

Which gave me:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (None, None, 19200) for input Tensor("input_19:0", shape=(None, None, 19200), dtype=float32), but it was called on an input with incompatible shape (19200,).
```

EDIT2:
I recieve the input in C++ from a 1D array and pass it with

```
  // Copy value to input buffer (tensor)
  for (size_t i = 0; i < fb->len; i++){
    model_input->data.i32[i] = (int32_t) (fb->buf[i]);
```

so what I pass on to the model is a flat array.

Comment: Keras models always expect input in batches and hence preserve the first dimension of `input_shape` to denote the batch size. So here you should change to `input_shape=(None, img_test_flat.shape)`. Can you try and update?

Answer (score 1):

Your use of shapes simply doesn't make sense here. The first dimension of your input should be the number of samples. Is it supposed to be 19,200, or 1 sample?

`input_shape` should omit the number of samples, so if you want 1 sample, input shape should be 19,200. If you have 19,200 samples, shape should be 1.

The reshaping layer also omits the number of samples, so Keras is confused. What exactly are you trying to do?

This seems to be roughly what you're trying to achieve but I would personally resize the image outside of the neural network:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

img_test = np.zeros((120,160)).astype(np.float32)
img_test_flat = img_test.reshape(1, -1)

reshape_model = tf.keras.Sequential()
reshape_model.add(tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(img_test_flat.shape[1:])))
reshape_model.add(tf.keras.layers.Reshape((120, 160,1)))
reshape_model.add(tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: tf.image.resize(x, (28, 28))))

result = reshape_model(img_test_flat)

print(result.shape)
```

```
TensorShape([1, 28, 28, 1])
```

Feel free to use the `Resizing` layer instead of the `Lambda` layer, I can't use it due to my Tensorflow version.

Comment: I am not sure which values I will have to adjust, could you post an example please?
I have an array with 19200 values (flattened image with (120,160)) and want to pass it to a Conv2D layer. Before doing that, I want to reduce the size to 28*28, so the input into the Conv2D is (28,28,1).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will use tflite on a micro controller and therefore cannot use img_test_flat = img_test.reshape(1, -1), but can only pass a flattened array to the model. That's why (to my knowledge) all reshapes need to be done withing the sequential. Any ideas on how to to this? I keep running into errors with it

Comment: There's no way to pass 2D data into the network? E.g., `(1, 19200)`? 1D makes it a lot more complicated